OpenProjectAsync Failed - Unable to open ArcGIS Pro Project Backup
ArcGIS Pro 3.2
I was using the Locate tool when ArcGIS Pro suddenly crashed and closed. It gave me the option to recover the file from backup when I re-opened it, but after I clicked yes, it popped up with a failed to open message. ProjectService::OpenProjectAsync Failed

How can I troubleshoot? I can open the project normally from windows explorer, but it lost some edits since my last save. I'm hoping for a way to get the recovered version before the crash.

You really want to contact Tech Support on these issues, because they may have more recovery tools available.
